# don't search underneath fixed div

Tags: css, html, fixed

the layout of my html page has a fixed div on top of the page. the content div then has a margin-top to compensate for the fixed div.

However, when the content gets scrolled down, if I do a search on page, the browser would sometimes show matches that would be underneath the fixed div, i.e. invisible.

For example, go to http://mincovlaw.com/services/worldwide_enforcement_checkup, scroll down a little bit, and do several searches for "know". You will see that the one closer to the top of the page will be found but will be hidden underneath the fixed div.

Is there a better way to achieve the same looks, while retaining the functionality of a search that does not get hidden?

Comment: Good news: in Chromium (Ubuntu 11.04) the first search term found is brought back into the visible area. You could, possibly, achieve a result with JavaScript, but I don't know what events, off-hand, you'd need to hook into, or how.

Comment: thanks, i do use javascript for anchor links on a similar page for these same reasons. it just was about the browser search that I wasn't sure of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: no, because that's exactly what you're doing: hiding content. Think of it as if content ceased to exist, that's exactly what you're doing and what you're looking for. Anyway, I doubt many people will search in the page, it's not THAT common

Comment: that's what frames are for i guess... but i agree, it's not THAT much of a big deal to redesign the whole thing.